# How to find out the module name of an installed plugin

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

How can I find out the module name of an installed plugin in Blender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the module name of a plugin under menu *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*. Locate the plugin in the list of installed add-ons and check the path that appears under *File*. In this example I check the module name for the *ScreenCast* addon. Notice that the name of the module appears after the `\addons\` part of the *File* path

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.4\scripts\addons\screencast_keys\__init__.py
```

So now I know that the module name for the *ScreenCast* addon is `screencast_keys`.

[image]

Alternatively, you can also check the folder of the plugin in the Blender installation directory, the module name is the same as the folder name `.../Blender/3.4/scripts/addons/<module_name>/`

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. But the module name seems to be "Turbo Render" for the plugin I´m searching. So it has a space in between. If i try to activate the plugin in the command line for background rendering, it says that this module name can´t be found.

Comment: I wanted to make a render with the command line where only one plugin should be activated and from the documentation i wrote this:  blender --factory-startup --addons Turbo Tools -b -y "C:\Users\timma\Videos\Test\Interior\1.blend" -s 1 -e 1 -a But the rror message i get is that it says that it can´t find the module name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use module `addon_utils` to inspect an addon, but it´s not in the API. Can be found in the Blender installation path *Blender > [Version] > scripts > modules > addon.utils.py*

First you need to get the addon module. Module name with `addon_module.__name__`

```
import bpy
import addon_utils  # not in API ; see addon_utils.py in blender_defaults/scripts/modules

addon_name = "Turnaround Camera" # addon UI name 

addon_module = [m for m in addon_utils.modules() if m.bl_info.get('name') == addon_name][0] # get module

###
print("\n*** %s ***" % addon_name)

# addon bl_info
print("--- bl_info")
print(addon_module.bl_info.get('name'))                                     # UI name
print(addon_module.bl_info.get('category', None))                    
print(addon_module.bl_info.get('version',(-1,-1,-1)))                       # -1 if not set
print(addon_module.bl_info.get('location', None))                     
print(addon_module.bl_info.get('author', None))                             # empty if none
print(addon_module.bl_info.get('description', None))                        # empty if none
print(addon_module.bl_info.get('doc_url'))                                  # empty if none
print(addon_module.bl_info.get('warning'))                                  # empty if none

# addon module info
print("--- module info")
print(addon_module.__name__)                                                # module name !!!
print(addon_module.__file__)                                                # install filepath
print(addon_module.__time__)                                                # install time
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(addon_module.__time__))                        # converted date + time

# addon_utils.check(addon_module.__name__)  tuple (loaded,enabled)
print("--- addon check")
print("is_loaded:", addon_utils.check(addon_module.__name__)[0])            # loaded
print("is_enabled:", addon_utils.check(addon_module.__name__)[1])           # enabled
```

Comment: Hello thank you very much but i didn´t quite understand what you mean. Do i have to place the script somewhere?

Comment: I'm a bit wondering why the question is marked with _python_ and _scripting_ if you're not so familiar with it. You get the module name following Harry McKenzie answer or might read these parts of the manual: [Texteditor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/text_editor.html?highlight=text+editor#text-editor) and Python [Scripting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/python.html?highlight=scripting#python-scripting)

Comment: Yes that were the only things i could choose to this topic, but your answer is also very good. I accept both.